# Change text color of table cell on hovering table row

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change color text of each row eg. red, when hovered on each row of a table.
I tried `&:hover` with color property, but it's not working.

```js
<TableRow
  key={row.id}
  sx={{
    "&:hover": {
      color: "red" // not working
    }
    // "& .MuiTableCell-root:hover":{ // --- on hover only hovered cell text color is changing
    //   color:"red"
    // }
  }}
>
  <TableCell align="left">{row.category}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="left">{row.name}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="left">
    <IconButton aria-label="delete">
      <span className="material-icons-outlined">
        delete_forever
      </span>
    </IconButton>
  </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

`MuiTableCell-root` override is done on `<TableRow>`, but this is affecting only each cell, but not entire row.

I need color to be changed on hovering each row? how to do that?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-mui-table-row-sofl-forked-9lfcw1) Demo.

Solution:

```js
<TableRow
 key={row.id}
 sx={{
  "&:hover .MuiTableCell-root, &:hover .material-icons-outlined": {
    color: "red"
  }
 }}
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:** Do this inside your `TableRow`

```js
<TableRow
  key={row.id}
  sx={{
    "&:hover .MuiTableCell-root, &:hover .MuiTableCell-root span.material-icons-outlined": {
      color: "red"
    }
  }}
>
  {/* some code */}
</TableRow>
```

Comment: This is almost working, but the "delete_forever" icon color inside the last `<TableCell>`  has not changed. Anything missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by

```
<Table
    sx={{          
      "& .MuiTableCell-root:hover": {
        color: "red"
      }
    }}
    /*...other code is omitted for the brevity*/
```

or by creating styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({ 
  tableCell: {
    "$hover:hover &": {
      color: "red"
    }
  },
  hover: {}
});
```

and then:

```
<TableCell
    className={classes.tableCell}
    component="th"
    scope="row"
 >
    {row.category}
 </TableCell>
```

Comment: Question is asking for `color` to change to red and not `background color`

Comment: @PratikWadekar thanks for pointing about that color should be applied to cell, not row. Thanks! Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

use "&:hover .MuiTableCell-root" with color red

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).